# Prove or disprove that every Holomorphic function preserving unboundedness is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

Roughly speaking as the title says: Prove or disprove that every holomorphic function preserving unboundedness is a polynomial.

Let $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be a holomorphic function such that for every unbounded set $ V \subset \Bbb C$ the image $f(V)$ is also unbounded.

> **Prove or disprove that $f$ must be a polynomial.**

Comment: Hint: What kind of singularity do you have at infinity?

Answer (score 7):

Let $V=\{z; |f(z)|\leq 1\}$. As $f(V)$ is bounded, $V$ must be bounded, there exist $R>0$ such that $V\subset B(0,R)$. For $z$ such that $|z|\geq R$, we have $|f(z)|>1$. Hence $f$ has a finite number of zeroes. Write $f(z)=P(z)g(z)$, $P$ a polynomial, $g$ entire with no zeroes. Then $\frac{1}{g(z)}=\frac{P(z)}{f(z)}$ is entire, bounded by $|P(z)|$, if $|z|>R$, hence bounded by $c|z|^m$ for large $|z|$. Then $1/g$ is a polynomial, hence a constant, and we are done.

Comment: This is a nice argument as well. Using Casorati-Weierstraß one would already be done at "For $z$ such that $|z|\geq R$, we have $|f(z)|>1$."

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't use a sledgehammer as a flyswatter.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** At $z=\infty$ your function has either a removable singularity, essential singularity or a pole.

If it is removable, the function has a finite limit at $\infty$, but this contradicts the given condition.

If it is essential, by Picard's Theorem, the function achieves all values, excepting one, infinitely many times. Use this information to build an unbounded set which goes to one value.

It follows that $f$ must have a pole at infinity. Use this to prove that $f$ is polynomial.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Picard is kind of overkill for this problem.

Comment: PS: I did not downvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Recall :[Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) **Little Picard Theorem:** If a function f : C → C is entire and non-constant, then the set of values that f(z) assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.
>
> **Great Picard's Theorem:** If an analytic function f has an essential singularity at a point w, then on any punctured neighborhood of w, f(z) takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single exception, infinitely often.

**Without loss of generality, Up to a shifting we assume that $z=0$ is not an exceptional point of $f$   otherwise replace $f(z) $ by $g(z)= f(z)-a $.** where a where a is chosen to be not an exceptional value of $f.$

Since $f$ is entire (then $f$ analytic with radius of convergence  $R=\infty $) we can write 
$$f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$$
we let
$$ h(z) = f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n }{z^n}$$ the point $z=0$ is either a pole of finite oder to $h$ or an essential singularity.

**Assuming, $h$ has an essential singularity** then by [great Picard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) set  $h^{-1}\{0\}$ is infinite in every neighborhood of $z=0$. Hence for $n>$ there  exists $|z_n|\le \frac1n$ such that $$h(z_n)=f\left(\frac{1}{z_n}\right)= 0$$

Hence the set $$V=\left\{\frac{1}{z_n} : n\in \Bbb N\right\}$$ is unbounded but $f(V)= \{0\}$ which is contradictory.

Hence necessarily, $z=0$ is polar of finite oder to $h$ that is there is $N$ such that $a_n=0$ for  $n\ge N+1$
 since in this case $h$ can be only written as

$$h(z) = f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=a_0 +\frac{a_1 }{z}+\frac{a_2 }{z^2}+\cdots +\frac{a_N }{z^N}$$

> which means that $f$ ia a polynomial and we have, 
>   $$f(z) = a_0 +a_1z +a_2 z^2+\cdots +a_N z^N $$

Thanks explanations from **@N.S.**

Comment: $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, therefore, by Picard great theorem, in some neighbourhood achieves some value infinitely often. Under the mapping $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ this becomes an unbounded set which is mapped to a single value.

Comment: @GuyFsone: That does not prevent $f(z)$ to be small along some path to infinity.

Comment: @Arthur I think that $-W_n(1)$ are roots of your equation, where $W_n$ are the countably many branches of the Lambert function.

Comment: @GuyFsone Again, Picard' Great Theorem applied to $f(\frac{1}{z})$ shows that none of your counterexamples work.

Comment: @GuyFsone Picards great Theorem implies that for your examples, the equation $f(z)=C$ has infinitely many solutions for all $C$ (excepting maybe one $C$). The set of solutions is the counterexample.

Comment: If you want a concrete set $V$, how about a union of ever smaller neighbourhoods around each of the infinitely many zeroes of your function? They are, as @N.S. said, situated at $-W_n(1)$ (the complex branches of the Lambert $W$ function) for all possible $n\in \Bbb Z$

Comment: The theory says that this transcendental equation has infinitely many solutions, and you ask us to provide them.

Comment: @GuyFsone Define $$V= \{ z | f(z) \in \{0, 1\} \}$$ Then $V$ is unbounded (by Picard's Great Theorem) and $f(V)$ is bounded. This proof works for ALL your examples.

Comment: @GuyFsone We have $f(z) = z(z+e^z)$. And I am telling you that $z+e^z$ has infinitely many zeroes. They all happen along the curve $\operatorname{Re}(z) = \ln |z|$ (because that's when $|z| = |e^z|$), and I can promise you that they happen because as you walk upwards along that curve, $z$ doesn't change much in argument at all, while for each $2\pi$ units upward you move along the curve, $e^z$ will have changed in argument by $2\pi$. By the intermediate value theorem, they have to be opposite somewhere in-between, at least if you put in some margins.

Comment: And no the burden is not on Arthur to prove to you that your answer is wrong, the burden is on you to provide the missing details for "plainly satisfies"... For your first example, $$W=\{ -W_n(1) | n\in \mathbb Z \}$$ is an unbounded set for which $f(W)=\{0\}$ is bounded... It is constructed explicitly.

Comment: You seem to just take a bunch of known functions and add $z^2$ to them. Since we are working in the complex plane, that does nothing to remove roots. It just makes them a bit more difficult to find.

Comment: @N.S. can you prove that $$V= \{ z | f(z) \in \{0, 1\} \}$$ is bounded I just read Picard theorem it  does not mention boundedness or unboundedness so where

Comment: @GuyFsone Yes I can. Let $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$. Since $g$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, by Picards Great Theorem $g$ takes the value $0$ or $1$ infinitely many times in any neighbourhood of $0$. Therefore, for each $n$ there exists some $z_n\neq 0$ with $|z_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ such that $g(z_n) \in \{0,1\}$. Let $$t_n=\frac{1}{z_n}$$ Then $ |t_n| >n$ and $$f(t_n)=g(z_n) \in \{0,1\}$$ This shows that $t_n \in V$ and $|t_n| >n$.

Comment: @N.S. thanks for explantion you are rightlet update my post

Comment: @GuyFsone No worry. PGT is one of the very powerfull not too known result in complex analysis. BTW, I din't downvote your answer :)

Comment: @N.S. see the update an let know if still have some objection by the I have cited you in the post. thanks very much I have learnt some great from you today .

Comment: @Arthur what about now? thanks for all your explanations I got it

Comment: That's a lot better.

Comment: You almost got it right. The function can have *one* exceptional value. For example $\exp(z)$ does not take the value zero, so $h^{-1}\{0\}$ *can* be empty or finite.

Comment: @MartinR yes you are right . But by shifting back to $z=0$ it will be ok right? I could take the expansion at $z=a$ instead of 0. Little Picard Theorem: If a function f : C → C is entire and non-constant, then the set of values that f(z) assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.

Comment: @GuyFsone: No, you need to consider $f(z) - a$ where $a$ is chosen to be not an exceptional value. (And your assumption $f(0) =0$ is irrelevant and not needed.)

Comment: @MartinR sure thanks edit made.

Comment: @GuyFsone Yes, that is the idea, and this is exactly what my answer is hinting towards ;)

Answer (score 1):

Casorati-Weierstrass gives a simple proof: We want to show that if $f$ is not a polynomial, then $f$ maps some unbounded set to a bounded set. But if $f$ is not a polynomial, then $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0.$ Thus by CW, $f(1/z)$ maps every $\{0<|z|<r\}$ onto a dense subset of the plane. Hence there is a sequence $z_k \to 0$ such that $|f(1/z_k)| < 1$ for all $k.$ Thus $f$ maps the unbounded set $\{1/z_k\}$ to a bounded set.